# Upload pdf, word, image in single post request in android

Tags: android

In my app i want to let user upload his resume in pdf/word format and also want to let user upload his photo. I am able to browse photo and resume but unable to send to php server in single request with other parameter

method for get photo

```
public void getPhoto(){
        Intent photoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoIntent, REQUEST_GALLERY);
    }
```

method for get Document

```
public void getDocument(){
        Intent docIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        docIntent.setType("application/msword,application/pdf");
        docIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(docIntent, REQUEST_DOCUMENT_CODE);
    }
```

on Activity result code

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            if(requestCode == IMG)
                imgUrI = data.getData();
            if(requestCode == CV)
                docURI = data.getData();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

i want to upload resume and photo with other parameters like

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
            String url="someurl.php";
            URL url = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data=
                      URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[1], "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("gender", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[2], "UTF-8")+ "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("resume", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[3], "UTF-8")+ "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("photo", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[4], "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));

            while ((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(string+"\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Error: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

my 3 and 4 parameter should be pdf/word or image, what is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Doesn't looks like proper method . Do it both task separately , upload image first then upload resume . Or else app may lag and  chances for crashing in low end devices even if you find the way to upload both at same instance.

Comment: Hi @SARATHV please tell me a way for upload only resume with this post request

Comment: In upload resume function choose resume from device storage by file chooser intent and get path of file in onActivityResult. Now you just use an async task to call server connection. Pass file path as url parameter. Make sure you are using proper php file with upload file queries.

Comment: May this blog will help you : http://www.androstock.com/tutorials/create-a-file-uploader-with-progress-in-android-android-studio.html